# How can I configure IP address from class E on Linux?

Tags: linux, networking

I would like to configure an IP address from class E, for example `241.0.0.2`.

Currently Linux (Linux-2.6.21.7-hrt1) returns the following answer:

```
ifconfig: SIOCSIFADDR: Invalid argument
```

Is there a way to do this?

(The reason for using class E is that I would like to avoid IP address conflicts with customer IP networks.)

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Can't you just use an A/B/C?

Comment: The "Class E" address is a "range reseved for future use" - so nothing uses it, you'd not be able to communicate.

Comment: Similar discussion:  [IPv4 Exhaustion: What About Class E Addresses?](http://packetlife.net/blog/2010/oct/14/ipv4-exhaustion-what-about-class-e-addresses/)

Answer (score 8):

The E class is not to be used. That is why the kernel does not permit setting such address. If you want a *local* IP, use one of the IP ranges designed for that purpose. Those are

```
10.0.0.0 – 10.255.255.255      (class A)
172.16.0.0 – 172.31.255.255    (from B class)
192.168.0.0 – 192.168.255.255  (from C class)
```

([See wikipedia for details.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network))

Comment: +1 Concur. That's what those address spaces are bloody well *for*.

Answer (score 4):

Use `ip` not `ifconfig`. Ifconfig is in the process of being deprecated by many linux distributions anyway.

`ip addr add 241.0.0.2/24 dev eth0`

Answer (score 2):

> I'll like to have internal IP communication between elements that will
>   NOT conflict with customer IP networks

Sounds like a perfect time to implement IPv6.

Answer (score 0):

From an expired IETF draft "[Redesignation of 240/4 from "Future Use" to "Private Use"](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-wilson-class-e-02)"

> Apple OSX has been confirmed to support the use of 240.0.0.0/4 as
> unicast address space.  Changes have been incorporated into
> recent
> versions of Sun Solaris and have been submitted for inclusion in
> the Linux kernel tree.  No plans have been announced for
> modifications to any version of Microsoft Windows, in part
> because
> of uncertainty over how to perform 6-to-4 tunneling in the
> absence
> of a definitive statement on whether 240.0.0.0/4 is "public" or
> "private" space.

So the majority of operating systems will not support this address range even if you can force a device to use it.